# Understanding the qualitative requirement

Tags: conditional-probability

From the book by Jayens Probability theory the logic of science I've found the following part which I dont understand:

It says there:

Given any change in prior invormation C -> C' such that B becomes more plausible but A doesn't change:

B|C' > B|C
A|BC' = A|BC

common sense demands that AB could only become more plausible, not less: 
AB|C' >= AB|C

That's what I understand but the next sentence makes no sense for me:
(it continues then) with equality if and only if A|BC corresponds to impossibility.

Could someone explain why A|BC is impossible if AB|C' = AB|C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\mathbb P(A,B \mid C)  = \mathbb P(A \mid B,C) \,\mathbb P(B \mid C)$$

and $$\mathbb P(A,B \mid C^\prime)  = \mathbb P(A \mid B,C^\prime) \,\mathbb P(B \mid C^\prime)$$

So if these are equal then you would have $$\mathbb P(A \mid B,C) \,\mathbb P(B \mid C)  = \mathbb P(A \mid B,C^\prime) \,\mathbb P(B \mid C^\prime)$$  which can  only be consistent with $\mathbb P(B \mid C) \lt \mathbb P(B \mid C^\prime)$ when $\mathbb P(A \mid B,C) \gt \mathbb P(A \mid B,C^\prime)$ (contrary to the original information) or when $\mathbb P(A \mid B,C) = \mathbb P(A \mid B,C^\prime)=0$